# Fine-Tuned ALBERT Question and Answering with HuggingFace

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, torch, bert-language-model

I'm trying to create a question and answering AI, I would like it to be as accurate as possible without having to train the model myself.

I can create a simple AI using the existing base models like so via their documentation:

```
from transformers import AlbertTokenizer, AlbertForQuestionAnswering
import torch
tokenizer = AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')
model = AlbertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')
question, text = "What does He like?", "He likes bears"
inputs = tokenizer(question, text, return_tensors='pt')
start_positions = torch.tensor([1])
end_positions = torch.tensor([3])
outputs = model(**inputs, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
loss = outputs.loss
start_scores = outputs.start_logits
end_scores = outputs.end_logits

answer_start = torch.argmax(start_scores)  # get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
answer_end = torch.argmax(end_scores) + 1
tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs["input_ids"][0][answer_start:answer_end]))
```

However this model doesn't answer questions as accurate as others.  On the HuggingFace site I've found an example that I'd like to use of a [fine-tuned model](https://huggingface.co/ktrapeznikov/albert-xlarge-v2-squad-v2)

However the instructions show how to train a model like so.  The example works on the page so clearly a pretrained model of the exists.

Does anyone know how I can reuse the existing models so I don't have to train one from scratch?

Comment: Training an existing model is covered by the docs and collateral examples for any DL framework.  You already have the phrase "fine tuning"; use it to find examples.  I know they existed for Torch when I first learned it in 2016.

Comment: @Prune I don't want to train, I just couldn't figure out how to use that existing model I found, turns out they hid the instructions on the page in a weird spot.  I'm going to test it out and then post an answer

Comment: Fine, so long as the solution you post is *new*.  You seem to be the victim of a poorly-written manual.  Given all of the Torch documentation in existence, I am skeptical that Stack Overflow is a good place to post your solution.  Please check for other sources first.  Look for how to load an existing model.

Comment: @Prune, you're definitely correct.  I've seen a lot of questions closed for less. However, I view questions like this as help using tools. e.g like questions about GIt, technically aren't programming related.

Comment: I'll post the answer regardless because I get frusterated when I can't find the answers on SO, and someone might find it useful (even if this question gets closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to grab an additional identifier when trying to request the model:

```
from transformers import AlbertTokenizer, AlbertForQuestionAnswering
import torch

MODEL_PATH = 'ktrapeznikov/albert-xlarge-v2-squad-v2';

tokenizer = AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH)
model = AlbertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH)
```

For future reference this information can be grabbed from the transformers use button.  Seem in the image below.

[image]